# Access Tuples elements

Tags: solidity, remix

I have the following tuple:

```
( , , uint256 standardDepositAmount, , )
```

I need to use the standardDepositAmount in a require, like:

```
require(standardDepositAmount == something)
```

how can i do that?

Comment: Exactly the way you've demonstrated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find more information in the [Solidity official documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/control-structures.html#assignment), but it's important to note that:

> Tuples are not proper types in Solidity, they can only be used to form
> syntactic groupings of expressions.

For this reason, in your case you should be able to read the `standardDepositAmount` variable without doing anything more, because it is already defined as `uint256` and it is (probably) already assigned.

Here a working example where the `require` function is satisfied:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.8.0;

contract myContract {
    uint index;

    function myFunction() public {
        ( , , uint256 standardDepositAmount, , ) = returnTuple();
        require(standardDepositAmount == 3);
        // do something...
    }
    
    function returnTuple() public pure returns (uint, uint, uint, uint, uint) {
        return (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    }
}
```

I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Neurone/83bfbd85ef79387f760154999eb4f192) for you. You can also do other experiments using Remix and the above smart contract following [this link](https://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.6.9+commit.3e3065ac.js&optimize=false&gist=83bfbd85ef79387f760154999eb4f192).